# Matching HD [something] pattern in awk

Tags: awk

This is the awk file called `densel`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
beg_ere = "^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]+(HD) [()]([[:space:]]*).*$"
}

$0 ~ beg_ere { print "MATCH" }
```

I am not getting MATCH being printed when use a file with the following line

```
## HD [opcon]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
  #beg_ere = "^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]+(HD) [()][[:space:]]*(.*)$"
   beg_ere = "^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]+HD [[][^]]*]"
}

$0 ~ beg_ere { print "MATCH" }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
MATCH
```

I left your original regexp there so you can easily compare it to the working one. Your main problem was using a bracket expression `[()]` that includes `(` and `)` when you should have used literal `[` and `]` around a repeated bracket expression such as `[^]]*`. The `[[:space:]]*(.*)$` would match any chars or no chars so it was doing nothing useful which is why I removed it. The `(` and `)` around `HD` were also doing nothing.

Comment: I need the `(...)` because I have to capture them later as in `title = gensub(beg_ere, "\\2", 1, $0)`.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem you asked about. If you have a different problem then accept an answer to this problem which you asked about and then ask a new question about that other problem with it's own [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have to match the possibility of having `## HD [something] keyword,key2` where I can have any number of keywords separated by commas.

Comment: That also has nothing to do with this problem you asked about. Again, ask a new question if you have one.

Comment: This shows the difficulty of writing a simple example.

Comment: Well, if you start removing the pattern, it will mess things up anyway.

Comment: It's not about writing a simple example, it's about writing a minimal example that demonstrates your needs but yes - asking a good question is often harder than providing a good answer.

Comment: I have no idea what "if you start removing the pattern, it will mess things up anyway." means, sorry.

Comment: If the script and sample input you provided in your question don't adequately cover your requirements then accept an answer to this question you asked and then ask a new question with it's own minimal, complete script and sample input/output that covers your additional requirements.

Comment: It was about removing `(...)`.  Anyway, let's focus upon having literal `[` and `]` surrounding any text in between.

Comment: This answer solves the problem you asked about. [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum so if you have different needs that you didn't describe in this question then simply ask a new question with it's own minimal, complete script and sample input/output that covers your additional requirements.

Comment: I have updated `beg_ere` to work on that one.

Comment: Please put it back as it was. Don't change the question after you have answers.