# Pattern that includes literal [ and ]

Tags: awk

With the following `beg_ere` pattern, how can I have `(asmb)` enclosed by literal `[` and `]` ?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  beg_ere = "^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]+(faml) [(asmb)]([[:space:]]*).*$"
}

$0 ~ beg_ere { print "MATCH" }
```

Where `faml` and `asmb` are user defined strings, or if not user defined are described by `"[[:graph:]]+"`.

In such case

```
beg_ere = "^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]+(faml) [([[:graph:]]+)]([[:space:]]*).*$"
```

I am not getting MATCH being printed when use a file with the following lines

```
## HD [opcon]

## HD [opcon] key

## HD [opcon] akey,bkey
```

where there can be any number of keys separated by commas.

Comment: I just showed you that in [my answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736780/133219) where I changed `[...]` to `[[]...]`.

Comment: What if I need to have `[[:graph:]]+` being enclosed by `[` and `]` ?

Comment: Then just make the surrounding `[` and `]` literal by using the bracket expression syntax I showed in [my previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736780/133219), `[[][[:graph:]]+]`, or by using the alternative double-escaping syntax in @glennjackman's answer below, `\\[[[:graph:]]+]`

Comment: I am unsure whether the following would work `ebl="\\[" ;  beg_ere = sprintf("%s(%s)", ebl, uasmb)` ?

Comment: Neither am I, I suggested `[[]` which I KNOW will work, not `\\[`, to escape the `[`. Why not try it and see?

Comment: I understand now, you mean enclosing `"["` in `"[...]"`.

Comment: Have tried `ebl="[[]" ; ebr="[]]"`.  How does it not work ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `How does it not work`, sorry. It may be time for you to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape them with backslashes.

However, because the regex is in a double quoted string, backslashes need to be escaped

```c
  beg_ere = "^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|//)[[:space:]]+(HD) \\[([[:graph:]]+)\\]([[:space:]]*).*$"
  # .....................................................^^^..............^^^
```

Comment: IMHO `[[]` is clearer than `\\[` and has the minor benefit that it would continue to work if copy/pasted into a literal regexp. Also, you don't need to escape `]` when it's not preceded by an opening `[`.

Comment: The problem is in how I construct the pattern with  `ebl="\\[" ; ebr="\\]"` and then using  `fm = "%s(%s) %s(%s)%s%s(%s)$"` followed by  `beg_ere = sprintf(fm, pn_ere, ufaml, ebl, uasmb, ebr, spc, kw)`.

Comment: This gets painful pretty quickly. You may need `ebl="\\\\["` or even `ebl="\\\\\\\\["` (I'm not entirely clear on the rules). If you're using GNU awk: [Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html)

Comment: I am using a dynamic regexp.

Comment: Use `ebl="[[]"` instead. Any time you find yourself doubling escapes consider switching to a bracket expression instead.